# Why do the PID obtained by the ps, netstat, and lsof commands differ?

Tags: linux

For example

[image]
[image]

why use "sudo netstat -tunlp|grep 11111" , PID is 11553.
why use "sudo lsof -i:11111", I get a lot of Pids.
why use "sudo ps -ef|grep 11111", PID is 10449.

I expect that they should be the same.

Comment: The ps command does not show the pid of the process 11111 but the pid of your grep command.